# insert selected multiple in database coldfusion

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I'm new with Coldfsuion and Jquery, Ajax, so how can I insert the checked item from the list into the database please.

```
<select name="list" id="list" class="Entry" multiple="multiple">
    <cfloop query="#qDta#">
        <option value="#qDta.GROUPID#">#qDta.NAME#</option>
    </cfloop>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you please show your attempt to make and execute a query?

Comment: Hi sir, i didn't know from where to start i only found php example with post method this why i asked maybe someone can help me with an exemple of coldfusion where a multipleselect is used.

Comment: Hi sphinx king, have you looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715600/coldfusion-multi-select-box-without-cfselect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the form is submitted, the receiving page will see the values in the `form.list` variable since the `name` of the field is `list`. The values will be in a comma-delimited list. Here is a query that can be run on the receiving in, of course with the tables and columns adjusted as necessary.

```
<cfloop list="#form.list#" index="groupId">
    <cfquery datasource="yourdatasource">
        insert into YourTable ( GroupId )
        values ( <cfqueryparam value="#groupId#" /> )
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: The question was weak but this answer is fine.  Perhaps the person who voted against it can explain why.

Comment: Good morning, Thank you dear sir you saved  me. I really appreciate what you did to me you helped me in my job have very nice day god bless you.

Comment: I'm not a fan of looping around a `cfquery`. That creates unnecessary load on the network and your database. It would be a bit nicer to buik insert the required rows in a single database connection and transaction by building the query from looping around the values instead.  -- EDIT: Also, to be clear, it wasn't my downvote. The solution does work; I just think it can work better. So don't think poorly of me. :-)